# how do I replace text within a string

Tags: regex, r, gsub, stat

I have a data such as

```
c("1988-10-25T11:12:47.00", "1988-10-25T14:43:24.36", "1988-10-26T14:14:25.60")
```

and I would like to replace everything after period to `A`. I tried to use gsub but after the period
all the numbers are different. What should I do?

the expected output `("1988-10-25T11:12:47A", "1988-10-25T14:43:24A", "1988-10-26T14:14:25A")`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I would like to make that to ("1988-10-25T11:12:47A", "1988-10-25T14:43:24A", "1988-10-26T14:14:25A")

Comment: put in the original question

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to do but try substr()

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sub`:

```
s <- c("1988-10-25T11:12:47.00", "1988-10-25T14:43:24.36", "1988-10-26T14:14:25.60")

sub("\\..*", "A", s)
# [1] "1988-10-25T11:12:47A" "1988-10-25T14:43:24A" "1988-10-26T14:14:25A"
```